# how to check Empty environment variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am setting an environment variable in my terminal with no value.

```
setenv ABC
```

Now I want to check in my bash script if this variable is set or not.

```
#!/bin/bash        

ABC_USAGE=0

if [[ -z "$ABC" ]] ;  then
  ABC_USAGE=$((ABC_USAGE+1))
fi
 echo $ABC_USAGE
```

I want to increase $ABC_USUAGE value only if  $ABC is set in terminal without any value. My code is increasing this value anyway. which is not expected result. please help..

Comment: even if you use just set to set the variable, as far as I know -z only checks if it is empty

Comment: I am setting it in my terminal outside the script. and want to check inside the script. This variable has not value.

Comment: then the if statement will always be true as the variable is empty even if it is set

Comment: yes , thats what the problem I'm facing .. Could you please help me with correct syntax ??

Comment: kindly look at the answer for explanation

Answer (score 4):

use this instead of the if expression that you are using

```
if [ -z ${ABC+x} ]
```

this will evaluate to be nothing if the variable isn't set and if the variable will be set the condition will be true.

This expression:

```
if [[ -z "$ABC" ]]
```

only checks if the variable has any value assigned or **if the variable is empty**

it will always be true if you just set the variable and the variable has no value assigned to it.